# How to upload an image and other list items to a SharePoint list using SPFx web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I have a SharePoint list called complex form, which has the following columns  Title, FirstName, LastName, About, Country, State, Street, City, Zip, Email, Company, Photo, the photo is an image column this is the method I am using to make the post request: no image is uploaded after making the request after inspecting the network tab the photo is shown as this- `Photo:{}`

```
  private AddContact = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const {
      Title,
      FirstName,
      LastName,
      About,
      Country,
      State,
      Street,
      City,
      Zip,
      Email,
      Photo,
      Role,
      Company,
    } = this.state;

    const assests = await sp.web.lists.ensureSiteAssetsLibrary();
    const fileItem = await assests.rootFolder.files.add(
      Photo.name,
      Photo,
      true
    );
    const img = {
      ServerRelativeUrl: fileItem.data.ServerRelativeurl,
    };
    const listName = "ComplexForm";

    try {
      const response: ItemAddResult = await sp.web.lists
        .getByTitle(listName)
        .items.add({
          Title: Title,
          FirstName: FirstName,
          LastName: LastName,
          About: About,
          Country: Country,
          State: State,
          Street: Street,
          City: City,
          Photo: JSON.stringify(img),
          Zip: Zip,
          Email: Email,
          Company: Company,
          Role: Role,
        });

      if (response.data) {
        const result = await response.data;
        console.log("Item created:", result);
        toast.success("Request created");
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,

          Title: "",
          FirstName: "",
          LastName: "",
          About: "",
          Country: "",
          State: "",
          Street: "",
          City: "",
          Photo: null,
          Zip: "",
          Email: "",
          Company: "",
          Role: "",
          isModalOpen: false,
        }));
      } else {
        console.error("Error missing response data");
        toast.error("Unable to create contact");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating item:", error);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve moved the image upload process to after the list item is created. Once the list item is successfully created, the image is then added as an attachment to the newly created list item. This should ensure that the image is correctly associated with the list item. Please try this and let me know if it works for you.

```
private AddContact = async (event: any) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const {
    Title,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    About,
    Country,
    State,
    Street,
    City,
    Zip,
    Email,
    Photo,
    Role,
    Company,
  } = this.state;

  const listName = "ComplexForm";

  try {
    const assests = await sp.web.lists.ensureSiteAssetsLibrary();
    const fileItem = await assests.rootFolder.files.add(
      Photo.name,
      Photo,
      true
    );
    const img = {
      ServerRelativeUrl: fileItem.data.ServerRelativeUrl,
    };

    const response: ItemAddResult = await sp.web.lists
      .getByTitle(listName)
      .items.add({
        Title: Title,
        FirstName: FirstName,
        LastName: LastName,
        About: About,
        Country: Country,
        State: State,
        Street: Street,
        City: City,
        Zip: Zip,
        Email: Email,
        Company: Company,
        Role: Role,
        // Update the Photo column with the URL of the uploaded image
        Photo: img.ServerRelativeUrl,
      });

    if (response.data) {
      const result = await response.data;
      console.log("Item created:", result);
      toast.success("Request created");

      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,

        Title: "",
        FirstName: "",
        LastName: "",
        About: "",
        Country: "",
        State: "",
        Street: "",
        City: "",
        Photo: null,
        Zip: "",
        Email: "",
        Company: "",
        Role: "",
        isModalOpen: false,
      }));
    } else {
      console.error("Error missing response data");
      toast.error("Unable to create contact");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating item:", error);
  }
};
```

[Get and show image in SPFx webpart from a Image column in a SP List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286662/get-and-show-image-in-spfx-webpart-from-a-image-column-in-a-sp-list)

Comment: Please this adds an attachment to the list how do update the Photo column instead of adding it to an attachment

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I've updated the code to update the Photo field directly with the `ServerRelativeUrl` of the uploaded image when adding the new item to the list.

Comment: After updating the code i got this error: data.error: {code: "-1, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException",…}}
odata.error
: 
{code: "-1, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException",…}
code
: 
"-1, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException"
message
: 
{lang: "en-US", value: "Error parsing comment. Expected: *, got s. Path '', line 1, position 1."}
lang
: 
"en-US"
value
: 
"Error parsing comment. Expected: *, got s. Path '', line 1, position 1."

Comment: Try passing the image directly `Photo: img,` instead of `Photo: img.ServerRelativeUrl,`

Comment: If the above doesn't work can you check the format that your SharePoint list expects for the Photo field. You might need to adjust the img object to match this format.

Comment: I already tried the passing the img but the Photo field shows this after making a post request Photo:{}

Comment: and this is the kind of data returned from the photo field:  Photo
: 
"{\"type\":\"thumbnail\",\"fileName\":\"servlet.png\",\"nativeFile\":{},\"fieldName\":\"Photo\",\"serverUrl\":\"https://accedeghana.sharepoint.com\",\"fieldId\":\"63756b94-c321-4c49-8cd9-e72f48d3260c\",\"serverRelativeUrl\":\"/sites/AccedeSite/SiteAssets/Lists/bf09bac5-289e-410a-a556-c67d75274574/servlet1.png\",\"id\":\"859c9d5c-e943-4074-bd70-c8ec52b0b076\"}

Comment: Thank you, the Photo field expects a JSON object with specific properties, including type, fileName, nativeFile, fieldName, serverUrl, fieldId, serverRelativeUrl, and id. 

`const img = {
  type: "thumbnail",
  fileName: Photo.name,
  nativeFile: {},
  fieldName: "Photo",
  serverUrl: "accedeghana.sharepoint.com", // Replace with your server URL
  fieldId: "63756b94-c321-4c49-8cd9-e72f48d3260c", // Replace with your field ID
  serverRelativeUrl: fileItem.data.ServerRelativeUrl,
  id: "859c9d5c-e943-4074-bd70-c8ec52b0b076", // Replace with your ID
};`

Comment: I tried another way and it worked the issue now is it works locally but after deploying i keep getting an error

Comment: What did you try and what error do you get?

Comment: I have fixed it actually used your method uploading the attachmentfile after creating the list item and for the error i created a new instance of the sp setup context in my constructor so it works perfectly now. Thank you so much for your help.